# Wait previous ajax call using method change() to call another change()

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, call

I want to call a change() method after finish call previous change method like this:

```
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceMarca').find('.marca').val(enlaceMarca).change();
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceProducto').find('.producto').change();


$('.marca').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ //ajax call to populate .producto select according a value of marca })
})

$('.producto').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ //ajax call})
})
```

But the problem is that call second change() method of .alcanceProducto without finished first change() method and I need call to second change() just after finished first change()

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the second change function in a callback of the first ajax call.  This is done by specifying a `function` to call on `success` of the ajax request.

```
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceMarca').find('.marca').val(enlaceMarca).change();

$('.marca').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({ 
       url: //url here,
       success: function(){
         $('#editMPS_structure .alcanceProducto').find('.producto').change();
       }
    })
})
```

Comment: Yes, is the first solution but I guess exists another function to use separately change() methods and not nested them